# Animating scrollTop in fixed height overflow without jank

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I am working on a project that uses the arrow keys as a form of focus handling, and am getting some major jank on my list scrolls. I recreated a --[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/fxyuzo6z/1/)-- to show what is going on, but it looks way better in the fiddle. I think this is because the elements I'm redrawing with scrollTop are much more complex for my application. Is there a better way to do this without using scrollTop? I understand that it is causing relayouts, and was curious if there was a better way.

Here is the main code from the --[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/fxyuzo6z/1/)--

```
function scroll() {
    var focusedBox = focused.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (focusedBox.bottom > containerBox.bottom || focusedBox.top < containerBox.top) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            var distance = focusedBox.height + 10;
            animate(distance, focusedBox.top < containerBox.top);
        });
    }
}

function animate(distance, up) {
    if (distance >= speed) {
        container.scrollTop += (up ? -speed : speed);
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            animate(distance - speed, up);
        });
    } else {
        container.scrollTop += (up ? -distance : distance);
    }
}
```

** To try it out, make sure you click inside the fiddle output area so that the key events will trigger, then use the down/up arrows **

I also need the scrollbar to work, so if the only better option is to use CSS3 transformY, I would have to build a custom scroller.

Comment: Do you have a link to your actual project somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put it up. I am creating a proof of concept for rewriting the PS4 console store in angular. Can't show the code/api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the actual code but check out this fiddle and see if it helps with anything:

http://jsfiddle.net/fxyuzo6z/4/

Basically I have removed the pulse animation that you have running on every focus event to be offset until there is a significant delay between keypresses. This gives more resources to the other animations that the browser needs to render, hopefully cleaning up the stutter/jank you are noticing. The timeout delay can be adjusted for your needs

CSS:

```
.focused {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.focused.animate {
        -webkit-animation:  pulse 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation:       pulse 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
        animation:            pulse 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

JS:

```
var pool = document.querySelectorAll('.item-row')
  , container = document.getElementById('item-container')
  , containerBox = container.getBoundingClientRect()
  , focused = pool[0]
  , focusIndex = 0
  , KEYS = {up: 38, down: 40}
  , keypressTimer = null;

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === KEYS.up && focusIndex !== 0) {
        focusIndex--;
        setFocus()
    } else if (e.keyCode === KEYS.down && focusIndex !== pool.length - 1) {
        focusIndex++;  
        setFocus()
    }
});

function setFocus() {
    clearTimeout(focused);
    focused.classList.remove('animate');
    focused.classList.remove('focused');
    focused = pool[focusIndex];
    focused.classList.add('focused');
    scroll();
    keypressTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        focused.classList.add('animate');
    }, 1000);
}

function scroll() {
    var focusedBox = focused.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (focusedBox.bottom > containerBox.bottom || focusedBox.top < containerBox.top) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            var distance = focusedBox.height + 12;
            animate(distance, focusedBox.top < containerBox.top, 20);
        });
    }
}

function animate(distance, up, speed) {
    if (distance >= speed) {
        container.scrollTop += (up ? -speed : speed);
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            animate(distance - speed, up, speed);
        });
    } else {
        container.scrollTop += (up ? -distance : distance);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

EDIT:

I did one more (not benchmarked) hyper-optimized (hopefully) test to increase performance by offloading the minor computations you are performing on every keydown into a Web Worker. Obviously this is not a cross-browser solution so it's up to you to determine if it's worth trying out:

http://jsfiddle.net/fxyuzo6z/5/

Comment: This is a great suggestion, and I will definitely use it. I'll wait to see if any other suggestions come in before handing you the dinero.

Comment: @ZackArgyle I have added an untested optimization here which makes use of Web Workers to offset some of the computations that are done. This may not actually produce any effect in this limited scope environment but your full example may have more going on.

Comment: This is good stuff, and I think it helped a little bit. Thanks for the help, I upvoted you and gave you the win.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using animate() recursive. Can't you just replace the whole scroll-function with this?

```
function scroll() {
$('#item-container').animate({"scrollTop": $(".focused").offset().top+$('#item-container').scrollTop()},'slow');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uoredfs8/5/

Comment: 1) I don't want to use jQuery in my Angular project. 2) This still uses recursion under the hood, so it literally helps in no way.

Comment: ok sry, was in full speed mode and didnt even notice. but: i tried to understand your question, but you dont tell what your problem really is. the word "jank" is not in my dictionary, so.. is it slow? is it broken? what is your problem?